# Executing stored procedure in Entity Framework - has no key defined. (Code First)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework. The stored procedure does not return any unique key in the returned row of data.

I get this error:

> **Type**: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0
>
> **Message**: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> SPProject.DTO.Result: : EntityType 'Result' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> Results: EntityType: EntitySet 'Results' is based on type 'Result' that has no keys defined.

Entity class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Database context :

```
public class ResultDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
using (var context = new ResultDBContext())
{
    var input1 = new SqlParameter("@q1", q1);
    var input2 = new SqlParameter("@q2", q2);
    var input3 = new SqlParameter("@q3", "%");

    var result = context.Results
                .SqlQuery("[dbo].[sp] @q1, @q2, @q3", input1, input2, input3)
                .ToList();
}
```

I read about using a complex type instead of an entity to map the output of a stored procedure without keys but haven't understood a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Add notmapped attribute to the class

```
[NotMapped]
public class Result
{
   ......
}
```

If you use the old .net you can try to add a key column to your result

or add to OnModelCreating of the dbcontext if you use net core

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Result>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```

Comment: Assuming I have to use EF Core here, right?

Comment: I had used [NotMapped] previously but it gave me a different error. modelBuilder is a part of EF Core and thats bringing in a different bunch of issues. 

`Message : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext. `

Comment: Since you  decided to use the legacy framework that is not supporte already, you  will have to use a workaround. What is preventing you from adding one more property to your Result class?. Make this property key and bind  to your sp result.

Comment: but my result has no key fields (it only returns 4 string fields) and none of them are unique keys

Comment: Change your stored procedure , add a primary key column  to select. it will be faster and more efficient then trying to find another way.

Comment: Solution that worked for me. Use Keyless attribute
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
namespace DotNetcoreEF.Models
{
 [Keyless]
 public class YourModel
 {
        string foo {get;set;}
        string bar {get;set;}
    }
}

using DotNetcoreEF.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace DotNetcoreEF.Entities
{
 public partial class yourCodeFirstContext
 {
  public virtual DbSet<YourModel> YourModels { get; set; }
    }
}
//T your class
//SQL your query or storeproc
//await yourContextInstance.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(SQL).ToListAsync();